# $E$ is elliptic curve over field $k$. $K$ is the field extension of $k$ adjoining all $N$ torsion points. $K/k$ separable?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, field-theory

Let $E$ be an elliptic curve over field $k$. $K$ is the finite field extension of $k$ s.t. all $N$ torsion points of $E$ are in $K$ coordinates. It is clear that $K/k$ is normal extension due to action of $Gal(\bar{k}/k)$ permuting $N$ torsion points solutions.

"$K/k$ is galois if $char(k)$ does not divide $N$"

$\textbf{Q:}$ How is $char(k)$ not dividing $N$ implying separability?

Ref. Lang, Elliptic Functions Chpt 2, Sec 1's field of N-division points.

Comment: Hint: calculate the degree of the extension in terms of $N$. Combine this with the fact that any element algebraic of degree $d$ prime to $p=char(k)$ has a separable minimal polynomial.

Comment: @KReiser I am going to take $Z_N\times Z_N$ as $N-$torsion points of complex elliptic curve. Then it follows easily that product of all $x$ coordinate is galois action invariant. Hence, from $(p,N)=1$, it follows separability as you suggested.

Comment: I'm confused - why do you say "complex elliptic curve" in your previous comment? The content of this question is in the case when the base field is positive characteristic.

Comment: @KReiser Ops. Sorry. The statement should be applied against positive characteristic case. Then I have to think about why there are finite many $N-$torsion points in field with positive characteristics. If that is the case, then it follows by what I said. For over complex number, there is nothing interesting.